# Hiding flicker and scroll animation when reloading a ColdFusion action page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I have a **ColdFusion** page with a `form` who's *action page* is itself

**main.cfm:**

```
<cfquery name="SearchRecords" datasource="ds"> 
    SELECT ...
</cfquery>

<cfform id="search_form" action="main.cfm" method="post">
    <table id="search_criteria">
        ...
    </table>
    <table id="search_results">
        <cfloop query="SearchRecords">
            ...
        </cfloop>
    </table>
</cfform>
```

The `form` is a simple record list of search results where clicking on one pops up a `cluetip` for editing the record.

When the record is saved and the `cluetip` dismissed, **main.cfm** is re-submitted so that the search query is re-run in order to get the latest copy of the modified record (along with the previous results).

**The two behaviors I'd like to manipulate/eliminate during the refresh is**

1. Immediate clearing ("white-ing out") of the existing page.
2. Scroll animation to saved scroll position.

**so that the screen remains static and updates only the edited record listing.**

(I realize ajax can be used and such, but I'm trying to work with what I've got rather than refactor)

Comment: You pretty much have to use ajax to accomplish this. Submitting the entire page is inherently going to reload the entire page.

Comment: I'm looking for some way to tell the browser to not clear the page right away, maybe a delay of sorts, to give time for the post, re-rendering, and re-scrolling to complete first.

Comment: If you are posting the form which re-renders the page, what's all this stuff about clearing?

Comment: @DanBracuk The clearing happens seldomly.

Comment: I guess you could have some sort of fixed table layout (cringe) which would keep things from moving around so much

Comment: You have no guaranteed impact on the browser's rendering. Even if it works with engine X, it might not work with engine Y. Using anchors is your best bet to at least keep the viewport.